# How to truncate all tables in realm android

Tags: android, realm

Hi im trying to truncateall tables in android when a user logs out. im using realms default path only.

```
realm = Realm.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

public void clearDB() {
    Realm.deleteRealmFile(instance);
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Update**

Use `realm.delete(Foo.class)` instead as `clear()` is deprecated. From 0.91.0
all `@Deprecated` methods will be removed.

---

Christian from Realm here.
That approach will work as long as you have closed all open Realm instances.
Another approach is clearing the tables you want like this:

```
realm = Realm.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

public void clearDB() {
  realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
     @Override
     public void execute(Realm realm) {
        realm.clear(Foo.class);
        realm.clear(Bar.class);
     }
  });
}
```

You can read more here: http://realm.io/docs/java/0.77.0/api/io/realm/Realm.html#clear(java.lang.Class)

Comment: under which folder proxy files get created??

Comment: If you are working with Android Studio it is here: /build/intermediates/classes/debug/io/realm, but you should be able to search for them using the Class action (cmd + o on Mac) .

Comment: for eclipse where should i find tat one

Comment: See here how to found out: http://realm.io/docs/java/0.77.0/#installation, but default is .apt_generated folder under your project (which is normally hidden).

Comment: One additional note regarding table classes in the database.
You can enumerate all tables classes with https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmConfiguration.html#getRealmObjectClasses--
It is useful if you don't need to clear all tables.

Comment: @mjosh use `delete()` instead of `clear()` since 0.90.1

Comment: I am working with Many to Many relation ship , will Clearing the Parent Class item clear the Realm list table items also ? or i have to delete that particular classes individually

Answer (score 10):

use realm.delete(Myclass.class);

```
realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    realm.beginTransaction();
    realm.delete(SuggestedAppDto.class);
    realm.delete(WifiSpotsDto.class);
    realm.commitTransaction();
    realm.close();
```

this worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to clear all tables, you may consider to use `realm.deleteAll()` method:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
realm.beginTransaction();
realm.deleteAll();
realm.commitTransaction();
realm.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

Delete all tables:

```
Realm.init(fragmentActivity);
    RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded().build();
    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfig);
    realm.beginTransaction();
    try {
        realm.deleteAll();
        realm.commitTransaction();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        realm.cancelTransaction();
    } finally {
        realm.close();
    }
```

delete one or more table:

```
  public void clearSearchHistory() {

    Realm.init(fragmentActivity);
    RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded().build();
    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfig);

    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            realm.delete(Foo.class);
        }
    });


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear all the tables without worrying about forgetting to clear new tables that you might create in the future, just do this

```
// mRealm is your realm instance

mRealm.beginTransaction();
Set<Class<? extends RealmModel>> tables = mRealm.getConfiguration().getRealmObjectClasses();
for (Class<? extends RealmModel> table : tables) {
    mRealm.delete(table);
}
mRealm.commitTransaction();
```