# Multiple tables in Android Realm

Tags: android, realm

Is it possible to have multiple tables within the same realm in Android?

If it is possible (as some other SO answers indicate, like this one: [How to truncate all tables in realm android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28084892/how-to-truncate-all-tables-in-realm-android)), how would queries work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to have multiple tables within the same realm in Android?

Yes, you just have to define multiple [`RealmObject`s](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#models).

```
public class Foo extends RealmObject {
    // fields
}

public class Bar extends RealmObject {
    // fields
}
```

[Queries work by "table"](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#queries). You can query for one table at a time, and you can also query across object links (relationships) if you really want.

```
RealmResults<User> result2 = realm.where(User.class)
                              .equalTo("name", "John")
                              .or()
                              .equalTo("name", "Peter")
                              .findAllSorted("name", Sort.ASCENDING);
```

Comment: Ha ha, that looks like something I should have been able to work out myself...thanks!

If someone from Realm is listening -- might be a good time to include this in your docs examples!